# Debug project written in multiple languages in VSCode

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code

I am wondering how people typically go about debugging applications that are written in multiple languages.

For example, you could have some javascript that calls some back end python code. Is there a way to set up debugging so that you can start debugging in one language i.e. javascript, and then switch to the python debugger once that bit of code gets called?

My use case is with PowerShell and some .NET class libraries but it seems like there might be a broader set of use cases.